# Чистота кода. Как "красиво" работать с функциями которые возвращают списки? Python

Tags: python, рефакторинг

Только начинаю изучать python и возникло пару вопросов по "минимизации" кода. Например функция re.findall() возвращает список найденных строк, но мне всегда нужна одна, и для того что бы ее "безопасно" получить приходится перед присваиванием проверять длину списка:

```
    re_email = re.findall('pattern',string)
    if len(re_email):
       #получаю первый элемент который мне и нужен
       email = re_email[0]
```

Или же при работе с функциями bs4 не применить сразу же следующую функцию get_text(), так как объект может быть не найден и будет вызвано исключение.
Хотел так:

```
name = html.find(iprop="usrname").get_text()
```

Приходится вот так:

```
item_name = html.find(iprop="usrname")
name = ''
if item_name:
    name = item_name.get_text()
```

Можно ли как то сократить написание данных конструкций?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В обоих случаях поможет тернарный оператор:

```
email = re_email[0] if len(re_email) else None
```

и

```
name = item_name.get_text() if item_name else None
```

Естественно вместо `None` можно подставить свой вариант страховочного значения.

Comment: Спасибо, именно такое и хотел))

Answer (score 1):

Пустые коллекции являются falsy в Питоне, поэтому можно `or` оператор использовать, чтобы значение по умолчанию задать, если получен пустой список вместо списка с одним элементом:

```
[item] = get_items() or ['default']
```

---

`re_email` это плохое имя для результата `re.findall()`. Если вы ожидаете получить список e-mail, то `emails` это лучше имя.

---

Если вам только одно значение нужно, то можно `re.search()` использовать вместо `re.findall()` функции, которая все (лишние) значения пытается найти:

```
m = re.search(pattern, text)
email = m.group(1) if m else 'default'
```